# EntityManager memory consumption

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jpa, out-of-memory, entitymanager

In one of our projects user can attach file to his account. We store these files in the MS-SQL database. So, we have the following piece of code:

```
@Entity
public class File extends AbstractEntity {

    @Lob
    @Basic
    private byte[] data;

    @Nullable
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public File() {
    }

    public File(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class SomeBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Long uploadFile(@NotNull byte[] data) {
        final PhysicalFile physicalFile = new PhysicalFile();
        physicalFile.setData(data);
        em.persist(physicalFile);
        return physicalFile.getId();
    }
}
```

And all was nice and pretty, before we tried to upload 40 MB file, and got `java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] Can't commit because the transaction is in aborted state`, which was caused by `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` inside the `uploadFile()` method.

I made a heap dump and looked at it in VisualVM.
[image: Heap Dump]

400+ MB of `char[]` and 100+ MB of `byte[]`. On the start our application, including `JBoss`, was using something about 60-65 MB of heap. So, the question is, why `EntityManager` consumes heap memory like crazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understaning to your issue as follows.

- All the entities that load/persist through an EntityManager stay in memory until you explicitly detach the entities from it (via EntityManager.detach() or EntityManager.clear() or EntityManager.close()). So it's better to have short-lived EntityManagers.
- As far as a RuntimeException occurs in the business logic, the em
  EntityManager remains open! You'll always want to avoid this sort of
  code. you can think of creating and closing the EntityManager as
  follows:

  ```
  public Customer getBestCustomerOfMonth() {
  EntityManagerFactory emf = ... ;
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  // business logic
  em.close();
  }
  ```
- You can nest the line for closing the EntityManager **em.close();** inside a finally
  block
- when using transactions outside an enterprise application server
  because you'll have to close (commit or rollback) the transaction in
  the same way you do for EntityMangers. In order for these resources
  (both EntityManager and underlying transaction) to be closed you'll
  need to make an additional level of nesting and write your code
  similar to this one:

  ```
       public Customer updateCustomer(Customer cust) {

         EntityManagerFactory emf = ... ;   EntityManager em =
       emf.createEntityManager();   try {
       EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
       try {
         t.begin();  
         // business logic to update the customer
         em.merge(cust);
         t.commit();
       } finally {
         if (t.isActive()) t.rollback();
       }   } finally {
       em.close();
         }       
      }
  ```

You may think this nested structure could looks like a bit of a mess, but it is really needed in precence of transactions.